# Text containing single quote as input value [PHP]

Tags: php

I try to show this string : «let's go» in a the value of an input tag

i wrote: 
$chaine="let's go";

```
echo "<input type=text name=test value='".$chaine."'>";
```

result: let

What can i do to show the correct string in this case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
echo "<input type=text name=test value='".htmlspecialchars($chaine, ENT_QUOTES)."'>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look at [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
htmlentities($chaine, ENT_QUOTES) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

This produces

```
<input type=text name=test value='let's go'>
```

You can see, that for HTML (--> your Browser) the value ends after "let". Everything after that is invalid (but ignored). Escape

```
$chaine = "let\'s go";
```

However, in HTML double quotes are prefered and omitting the quotes is also no good style

```
$chaine="let's go";
echo '<input type="text" name="test" value="'.$chaine.'">';
```

In this case you must escape every double quote.

Comment: You're just telling him what to do, but not how.

Comment: Thats wrong. The second code snippet show, how to escape, the last one is a working example.

Comment: Escaping double quotes is not the way to go, it should be `..."' . htmlspecialchars($chaine) . "'...`

Comment: I should have made that clearer: By "show, how to escape" I just mean "how to (very simply) escape the quotes". Of course with `htmlspecialchars()` its much safer.